# Optimizing Three Address Code

Tags: optimization, assembly, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, machine-code

I have the following three address code, where n is some external constant:

```
   x = 0
   i = 0
L: t1 = i * 4
   t2 = a[t1]
   t3 = i * 4
   t4 = b[t3]
   t5 = t2 * t4
   x = x + t5
   i = i + 1
   if i < n goto L
```

I would like to optimize it as much as I can. Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
    x = 0
    i = 0
    t1 = -4
L:  t1 = t1+4
    t5 = a[t1] * b[t1]
    x = x + t5
    i = i + 1
    if i < n goto L
```

Can anyone offer corrections/additional optimizations?

Comment: Does the target architecture support complex memory addressing and is the codegen capable of recognizing simple patterns to map to that?

Comment: There isn't really a target architecture here. This is more of a pedagogical example I'm working through to learn about compiler code optimization.

Comment: Ok. Too bad. Otherwise, I would have suggested calculating offsets to the end of the arrays, using a negative index (then the `i < n` test becomes `i == 0`, which would get rolled into the addition) and addressing the arrays like `end[4 * i]`. That's an interesting optimization IMO, but it's not target independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
    x = 0
    t1 = (n-1)*4
L:  t5 = a[t1] * b[t1]
    x = x + t5
    t1 = t1 - 4
    if t1 >= 0 goto L
```

I don't know what the target machine is, but the last two instructions could typically be done with something like `SUB` / `JNS` (which saves a comparison).

Comment: t1 = (n-1)*4 isn't valid three-address code. Also, I'm not sure how that's equivalent. T1 has to be 0 initially according to the original - there is no guarantee that n-1 will be 0.

Comment: Why would it not be valid 3AC if `n` is constant (which you stated that it is in the question)? The value of the expression can be evaluated at compile-time. As for how it's equivalent; the code (from my understanding) calculates the sum of products between `a` and `b`. The order in which the summation is done should not matter (it doesn't affect the result), so my answer loops backwards from n-1 to 0, since that typically is more efficient.

Comment: +1 for you. According to the Wikipedia article on TAC: "Expressions containing more than one fundamental operation are not representable in three-address code as a single instruction." So I think it would need to be broken into t1 = n-1 and t1= t1*4. Other than that, I think your representation is actually equivalent, so I retract my doubt about that. However, I'm still not convinced that this is more optimal - although you have one less instruction, you've introduced an additional MUL operation. You might be right though, I'm just not sure.

Comment: The extra mul is not in the loop though, and how is optimality even defined if you don't have a target architecture? Fewest instructions? Fewest executed instructions? Are some instructions weighted "heavier" than others?

Comment: Maybe I was a bit unclear in my previous comment: since `n` is constant you could evaluate `(n-1)*4` at compile time, e.g. if `n` is 5 the 3AC instruction could be `t1 = 16`.